# Word shows error message when saving a docx on an SQL FILESTREAM

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, streaming, sql-server

I have a SQL Server. I created access to a file stream table.

I have a UNC path to the specific folder \Pc\mssqlserver\DBShare\Files. I can open the explorer and I can navigate through the subfolders and I see all files in it.

I can copy files into the folder. I can delete files. No errors.

- Now I open Word (Office Professional 2016).
- I create a new document and I press Save.
- I enter a valid path to the SQL file stream and press Save

The file is created with 0 Bytes in the file stream. Word shows the following error message:

```
There has been a network or file permission error. The network connection may be lost. (path of the file.docx)
```

Same happens, when I open an existing document and change something and press save.

Did I misconfigured something?

Can I use an SQL file stream as a standard storage for Office products?

PS: I know that I can only create and delete files. Renaming isn't possible. Is this the reason?

I also tried to set the advanced option to copy network files to the local PC when editing. But didn't helped either.

PS: I have currently an open support case at Microsoft. But there is no advance at all. I can repro the error easily on my machine using it as server and client.

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to get this to work through file explorer. I didn't think this was designed to be directly used this way. My experience is that you write a tool or service to send the file to the SQL Server. My guess at why this is failing would be because Word has a unusual way of saving files as a two step process. Perhaps it creates a 0 byte file first to confirm it has permission, then it writes the data?

Comment: No. It is a normal file system.

Comment: Two links with a full description https://www.sqlshack.com/filestream-in-sql-server/
https://www.sqlshack.com/managing-data-with-sql-server-filestream-tables/

Comment: We use a plugin for Word that saves it to the FileStream. Code like this: https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/ Plugins can be created easily with tools like this: https://www.add-in-express.com/